# About the mechanism of opening of the band gap in topological insulator with the inclusion of SOC

Tags: band-structure, condensed-matter, symmetry, spin-orbit-coupling, topological-insulators

When we work on the topological insulator (protected by time reversal symmetry ), it is often said that the SOC is the main ingredient because it is a way to open a gap when the band inversion present. I want to ask what is the mechanism cause the gap to be opened ? More precisely, I found that SOC will cause the splitting of energy band. Let’s say if the system contain both time reversal and inversion symmetry, each energy band must be 2-fold degenerate. However the SOC term don’t violate these symmetries, where is the splitting come from ?

Comment: I think figure 1 of this paper is kind of self-explanatory: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06508

Comment: You can also have a look here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1546/5685

Comment: Were the comments by Davide helpful? Let us know if you're still working on this or if you found the answer!